# Python script causes XQuartz to launch

Tags: python, python-2.7, xquartz

I'm using Mac OS 10.9 trying to make a python script work.  However for some reason each time I start the script from the terminal it causes XQuartz to start.  The version of Python is 2.7.5.  Whenever I quit XQuartz I get this message in the console:

```
XIO:  fatal IO error 35 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server "/tmp/launch-mumXCj/org.macosforge.xquartz:0"
      after 24 requests (23 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

I'm not exactly sure why.  When I run my script (a very simple web server) in WingIDE it works perfectly, but not from the terminal.

This gist contains my code: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/claydiffrient/7c076164143aedcb25ff)

Comment: WingIDE already has XQuartz running, likely masking this from you. Your script apparently needs an X server running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently, the shebang *must* be the first line.  There can't be any comments before it which was causing the problem.  With comments moved afterwards it works just fine.